# How to best indicate to git that a source file is being split?

Tags: git

I sometimes want to spin off part of the contents of a source file into a new one (or more, but let’s start with 1 -> 2 and scale up from that): for instance say I have a class in its own file A, and I decide part of it needs to be its own class, in its own file B, that the original class will be a client of.

Suppose also there are other people working on A in another branch for the day-to-day development activities, while my work is longer-term development work: I would like those changes to merge well (or at least, not too badly) in my branch.

In most version control systems, I would declare B to be a copy of A, then remove in A what I intend to be keep in B, and remove in B what I intend to keep in A. This gives acceptable results once merges occur. I haven’t found a way to express this to git (no `git copy` command, in particular). Is there one I missed?

Comment: In which other version control system have you seen this feature? I'm curious because I can't recall seeing it in any. And I don't think git has this function, because git does not operate on individual files in that manner.

Comment: @fredrik Subversion has [`svn mv`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.move.html) and [`svn cp`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html).

Comment: And what does those do that a system `mv` or `cp` does not do? Reading those documentation pages it just seems to be a normal move or copy. Anyhow, git does not track files between branches only in the commit chain

Comment: @fredrik Where Git guesses, most version control systems do explicit rename and copy *tracking*. `svn cp` explicitly remembers that the file was copied. `svn mv` remembers it as a copy and delete. Others, like Mercurial, remember both. When two branches have renamed or copied the same file they use that info to help the merge; for example if both renamed the same file it can raise a conflict. See "File Renames" and "Merge File Renames" in this [Comparison of Version Control Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_version-control_software#Features).

Comment: Linus Torvalds argues (correctly, IMO) that file identity ("what was file foo is now file bar") is not interesting and in some cases has negative value. What we want is "the code you're looking for is in files foo and/or bar" at the appropriate time. Of course, Git doesn't actually *provide* this today (not properly anyway) and recorded file-renames act as a proxy that we (humans) use to approximate what we really want.

Comment: Subversion and Mercurial are indeed the main two that support copy and which I expected the reader to recall; I have known others, such as ClearCase (even if in that one particular case the support for mv/cp is by simple virtue of ClearCase posing as a filesystem: everything you perform, ClearCase sees and knows about it… ClearCase is Santa Claus!), but don't expect those to be a common reference. And I will readily admit to being… disappointed by Subversion in general in this scenario, and it's not going to improve https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SVN-898

Comment: I am willing to play by the rules of the version control system and see where that leads my team and I; and git does have a track record of generally handling merges well, be it with the Linux kernel or elsewhere. I will just note that the current design (or lack thereof) is putting a tremendous amount of responsibility and pressure on the poor integrator performing the merge, and on whichever version of git he happens to have laying around locally.

Answer (score 2):

Git does not record renames and copies. Instead, it performs heuristics to guess if a file is a rename or copy. Generally by checking what percentage of the content the files have in common. The default is 50%. [The configuration can be endlessly tweaked](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).

`git-merge` can be configured to detect copies and renames. It generally follows what `git-diff` is set to do. If you set [`diff.renames`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-diffrenames) to `copies` then [`merge.renames`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-mergerenames) will use that.

---

You can do some things to make it more likely that Git will detect copies and renames. For example, let's say you want to split one file into two files. If you copy the code, and change it, and rename the files in a single commit Git might have a hard time recognizing it. Instead, separate moving the code from changing the code into its own commits.

For example, let's say you have one file all.code with one class two methods. You want to split this into two classes in two files.

```
# all.code
class All
  def one
     ...
  end

  def two
     ...
  end
end
```

First do the refactoring into two classes within that file. Commit only that. This is a normal change which Git will have no trouble recognizing.

```
# all.code
class One
  def call
     ...
  end
end

class Two
  def call
     ...
  end
end
```

Then move out one of the classes to a new file. Make no further changes. Commit only that. This will help Git recognize the relationship between all.code and two.code. It may help to move the larger of the two classes.

```
# all.code
class One
  def call
     ...
  end
end

# two.code
class Two
  def call
     ...
  end
end
```

Finally, rename the original file. Commit only that. Since the content of the file did not change Git will have no trouble recognizing the rename.

```
# one.code
class One
  def call
     ...
  end
end

# two.code
class Two
  def call
     ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that at the moment, at least, the existing Git code doesn't make use of these helpful hints. I have hopes for merge-ORT to be better...

Comment: I appreciate your answer; it might be our best hope for storing information such that when the merge eventually happens, the right thing occurs (since git performs all the code tracking at the last moment anyway). I will just note that source language limitations may make this less straightforward than it ought to be: for instance, some languages will require each class to be contiguous, and hence force a code reshuffle at the first step, before we separate the two anyway.

Comment: @PierreLebeaupin You can minimize the hassle by making the merge as small as possible. Tell everyone to get their branches up to date. Once that's done, merge the minimum possible change to do the split. Then tell everyone to update their branches again.